# Magento can not add product programmatically

Tags: magento

i have use below code to add product in magento but not success ,anyone know how to do?

[code here](http://postimg.org/image/tgq74521l/)

[code txt file](http://jdarts.com/code.txt)

`require_once $mageFilename;`

`Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);`

`umask(0);`

`Mage::app();`

`Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));`

`$product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();`

`$product->setSku('A123');`

`$product->setAttributeSetId(4);`

`$product->setTypeId('simple');`

`$product->setName('Some cool product name');`

`$product->setCategoryIds(array(19));`

`$product->setWebsiteIDs(array(1));`

`$product->setDescription('Full description here');`

`$product->setShortDescription('Short description here');`

`$product->setPrice(39.99);`

`$product->setWeight(4.0000);`

`$product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);`

`$product->setStatus(1);`

`$product->setTaxClassId(0);`

`$product->setStockData(array(
    'is_in_stock' => 1,
    'qty' => 99999
));`

`$product->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'));`

try {

$product->save();

}

catch (Exception $ex) {

}

?>

Comment: What specifically isn't working? Please add your code to the question itself.

Comment: Add your code here directly, instead of text file link.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: No error get,but no product was added,THX

Comment: What are the script file location and mage file location??

Answer (score 0):

i hope it may be`mage.php path issue`.Try put proper of mage file path

Suppose,My Magento path is  `/home/abc/www/www/` in server.
and my script file location location in  `/home/abc/www/www/try/dot/myscript.php`

If you try to include mage.php  from myscript.php then

```
$mageFilename = '/home/abc/www/www/app/Mage.php'
```

or

```
$mageFilename = '../../app/Mage.php'
```

i have run your  script with modify mage.php file location call in script.it is works

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this code to add/update products on Magento.

```
<?php
include_once("app/Mage.php");
Mage::app();
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));

$counter = 0;
```

I have this function to get (or create) a product by SKU:

```
function GetProduct($sku)
{
    global $counter;
    echo $sku;
    $p = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $productId = $p -> getIdBySku($sku);       
    if($productId)
    {
        echo "!";
        $p -> load( $productId );
    }
    else
    {
        $p->setTypeId('simple');
        $p->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH); 
        $p->setStatus(1);
        $p->setTaxClassId(7);
        $p->setWebsiteIDs(array(1)); 
        $p->setStoreIDs(array(1)); 
        $p->setAttributeSetId(4);
        $p->setSku($sku);
    }
    echo "...";
    $counter++;
    echo " ".$counter;
    return $p;
}
```

Here's the function to save the product:

```
function SaveProduct($p)
{
    try
    {
        if (is_array($errors = $p->validate()))
        {
            $strErrors = array();
            foreach($errors as $code=>$error)
            {
                $strErrors[] = ($error === true)? Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Attribute "%s" is invalid.', $code) : $error;
                echo $strErrors[0];
            }
            $this->_fault('data_invalid', implode("\n", $strErrors));
        }
        $p->save();
        echo "\n";
    }
    catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e)
    {
        $this->_fault('data_invalid', $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

And finally I'm calling like this:

```
$product = GetProduct('sku1');
$product->setData('thumbnail_label', 'sku1');
SaveProduct($product);
unset($product);
$product = GetProduct('sku2');
$product->setData('url_path', 'plastic-hat.html');
SaveProduct($product);
unset($product);
$product = GetProduct('sku3');
$product->setData('thumbnail_label', 'sku3');
SaveProduct($product);
unset($product);
$product = GetProduct('sku4');
$product->setData('thumbnail_label', 'sku4');
SaveProduct($product);
unset($product);
$product = GetProduct('sku5');
$product->setData('thumbnail_label', 'sku5');
SaveProduct($product);
unset($product);
```

I run this code from the command-line as there is a memory leak running it this way. You can only get so many products updated before it blows the memory and you have to edit and re-run the code to keep going, but it works and it's relatively fast.

You should be able to slot your code in quite nicely.